# Autowire non-serializable activiti TaskService into Component used in Spring Web Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, activiti

I have @Component that I use in my Spring Web Flow, in that Component I need to autowire org.activiti.engine.TaskService which not implements Serializable, but all object in flow scope need to be serializable, I receive this exception:

org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.activiti.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl

How can I use TaskService in my spring web flow component?

Comment: why not set TaskService as transient?

Comment: Because after deserialization it becomes null and I can't use it.

Comment: You should only store variables in db. Saving a service does not nake sense at first place.